# How to append the text from source file into destination file before the EOF in a destination file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, copy, append

I have 2 files. File 1: source.sh File 2: destination.sh

I want to insert the contents of File 1 into File 2. But i don't want to insert the contents at the end of the file. The last line of File 2 is "}"

**I want to insert the content of File 1 into File 2 before "}"**

**My exact code:**

```
xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

 xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

 xxx_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
```

**My destination.sh**

```
{
    zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    zzz_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"


    ccc_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    rrr_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
    }
```

I need to insert source.sh into destination.sh before **}**

Since it is in production i don't want to hard code any number to define the EOF...
Any help is appreciated

As suggested i created the file and ran the command

```
ed -s file2.txt < script.ed
```

[image]

Comment: The file format is unclear, does it has indentations and empty lines at the end?  Also this question has been asked in Unix stack exchange rigth?

Comment: @Jetchisel It has no indentations and yes the file has empty lines at the end.I did not knew about the qusetion posted there

Answer (score 0):

You try can using `ed(1)`

```
cat file1.txt
```

Output

```
xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

xxx_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
```

Second file

```
cat file2.txt
```

Output

```
{
zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

zzz_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

ccc_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

rrr_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
}
```

The code

```
printf '%s\n' '$,/^}/-1a' "" . '$,/^}/-1r file1.txt' ,p Q | ed -s file2.txt
```

Output

```
{
zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

zzz_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

ccc_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

rrr_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

xxx_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
}
```

To use a script for ed

```
cat  script.ed
```

Output

```
$,/^}/-1a

.
$,/^}/-1r file1.txt
,p
Q
```

Now you can run

```
ed -s file2.txt < script.ed
```

- Replace the `,p Q` with just `w` to edit the file `in-place`
- My solution works on the file format that I have posted, you need to fix the file format in your post if that is not the case.

Comment: The above method is not working...Contents are not getting inserted...

Comment: Is there any way to insert the contents in the middle...if not possible beforr EOF..

Comment: Do you have carriage return on your files?

Comment: I gave you my sample and test case, so the only thing left is to check if you have carriage return on the files...

Comment: I used the command printf '%s\n' '$,/^}/-1a' "" . '$,/^}/-1r file1.txt' ,p Q | ed -s file2.txt ...How to save the output in file.txt

Comment: Redirect to the file.txt add at the end  `> file.txt`

Comment: I have created the file script.ed and gave the contents. and i ran the command as suggested and i have attached output .am getting ? as output
Can u pls help me

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: `ed -s file2.txt < script.ed > out.txt`

Comment: When i run ed -s file2.txt < script.ed > out.txt am getting ? as output...

Comment: printf '%s\n' '$,/^}/-1a' "" . '$,/^}/-1r "${my_file5}"' ,p Q | ed -s "$filenamelocal" >  "$filenamelocal" is this correct to redirect out to "$filenamelocal

Comment: Make sure the filenames are correct, that means use the correct filenames in the script. Other than that I don't know what to tell you anymore...

Comment: Ok, what do you want? you want to edit the file in place or just create a new file for the output? Your question keeps changing...

Comment: I you want to edit the file in-place change `,p Q` to just `w` I have mention that in the answer already..., Also shell variable does not expand inside single quotes... The answer is there you just need to adjust it to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

So the general proble is that you have two files (say for simplicity X and Y), and you want a resulting file, containing first all but the last line from X, than all of Y, and finally the last line from X. Translating this literally:

```
cat <(head -n -2 X) Y <(tail -n 1 X) >RESULTFILE
```

Comment: I have 2 file X & Y. I need to edit the file Y. I need to append the contents of X into Y. Contents should be appended before the last line of Y

Comment: Then just do a `mv RESULTFILE Y` afterwards.